# call a function in parent of parent angular 4

Tags: angular, components

I have a child of a child component

I want to call a function in the parent

CompA
      CompB
            CompC

My CompC want to call a function in CompA

Do I have to add output to C that call a function in B that output to B and call a function in A ?

Is there a more direct way?

Comment: create service and use rxjs BehaviourSubject

Comment: yes, shared service is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @chellappan comments on create behaviorsubject and emit events. You can also achieve using DI.

You can import CompA in Compc and call like this.

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private appc: AppComponent){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.appc.callfromChild();
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjmxe6

Answer (score 0):

Inject parent component using `forwardRef` and call parent `f()` from child as below:

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) public _parent: ParentComponent){}

ngOnInit(){
    this._parent.f();
}
```